# Taking the count of number of 'table' tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

This is my HTML code

```
      <div class="tableStyle myWebsiteTable">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="site0" class="site active">
        <thead>  
            <tr>  

            </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="websiteDetails">
                <td colspan="5">
                <div id="websiteDetails0" class="divWebsiteDetails" style="display: block;">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                                                        <tr id="190">
                                <td>index</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr class="addPage">
                                <td align="center" colspan="5"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr><!--Website Details-->
        </tbody>
      </table>
                <table id="addNewSiteTable">
        <thead> 
          <tr>               
          </tr>
         </thead> 
      </table>
</div>`<br/>
```

Now table get added dynamically to this structure.I want to write some logic based on the no of table inside the first `div`.I tried doing this but did not work `$('myWebsiteTable').children('table').length)`
 
PLease suggest the correct way to achieve it
Thank you

Comment: THAT WAS ABSOLUTELY STUPID!!!!!!!!! Working LATE can seriously have an impact!!I agree now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `.` before class in Class [Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygjwR/)**

```
$('.myWebsiteTable').children('table').length
```

Also make sure you have added jQuery and elements are added to DOM.

You may need to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) as children will give you only first level childs where as find will get all the tables in descendants.

```
$('.myWebsiteTable').find('table').length
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.myWebsiteTable').children('table').length
```

And if you actually want to count nested tables:

```
$('.myWebsiteTable table').length
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it's class

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

`$('.myWebsiteTable')`

Answer (score 1):

try this, this is more helpfull for you

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/TLTuK/6/)